# Matillion for Amazon Redshift support for job monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, jobs, matillion

I am working on Amazon Matillion for Redshift and we have multiple jobs running daily triggered by SQS messages. Now I am checking the possibility of creating a UI dashboard for stakeholders which will monitor live progress of jobs and will show report of previous jobs, like Job name, tables impacted, job status/reason for failure etc. Does Matillion maintain this kind of information implicitly? Or I will have to maintain this information for each job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matillion has an API which you can use to obtain details of all task history. Information on the tasks API is here:
https://redshiftsupport.matillion.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2720083-loading-task-information?b_id=8915

You can use this to pull data on either currently running jobs or completed jobs down to component level including name of job, name of component, how long it took to run, whether it ran successfully or not and any applicable error message.

This information can be pulled into a Redshift table using the Matillion API profile which comes built into the product and the API Query component. You could then build your dashboard on top of this table. For further information I suggest you reach out to Matillion via their Support Center.

Answer (score 0):

The API is helpful, but you can only pass a date as a parameter (this is for Matillion for Snowflake, assume it's the same for Redshift). I've requested the ability to pass a datetime so we can run the jobs throughout the day and not pull back the same set of records every time our API call runs.